# Attempting to identify any number in a given range that has the same first and last digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I am trying to find the all the possible numbers in a given range which have 1st and 1ast digit equal with below mention code:

```
****Constraints: 1<n<m<10^18 ****

def Digits(n,m):
     c=0
     for i in range(n,m+1):
        i=str(i)
        if i[0]==i[-1]:
            c+=1
     return c
```

All of the numbers I'm searching for can be found, printed, or counted, however I'm unable to beat the time complexity of the code because the time complexity is 1.0sec and this function takes 5 sec to get the desired output. Would someone be able to improve the code such that the output takes less than a second? I'm also attempting to identify any patterns, and whenever I do, I'll post it. Any advice or assistance is appreciated.

I made an effort to identify every number whose first and last digits are equal, but I was unable to finish in time. To reduce the time, I anticipate making certain code improvements.

Comment: consider a range `1000-9999`. How many numbers are there that start and end with `1`, like `1xx1`? Do you need to iterate the whole range to find out?

Comment: my function that - it iterates through the given range to count down the number. But my time complexity is too high. Suppose u give the upper range of 10^18 my system will take forever to run. I want to decrease the time.

Comment: my point is that you can find out the answer without iterating. Just look at the example I gave you.